# React/JavaScript: Where does "item" come from in this function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a function from a book that I am working through:

```
function byQuery(query) {
    return function(item) {
        return !query ||
            item.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Its purpose is to filter a list of objects--but I am not sure where `item` is coming from--its only use (in the given code) is like so:

```
<List list={(list || []).filter(byQuery(query))} />
```

Comment: Look up the docs for Array.prototype.filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` comes from the argument that [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) provides to its callback function. `byQuery(query)` **returns a function** is basically the function that is used by `filter`. It would be similar to this

```
{(list || []).filter(function(item) {
    return !query ||
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
})}
```

Comment: Thank you, now that I see it in the way you have written it, it makes a lot of sense! I will accept your answer when I can.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)